# concat string in shell command line

Tags: linux, shell

I need some help to finalize a command line. I need to get a property name "server.port" in some files "applications.properties", and then make a curl on "myIp:server.port/health"

I get properties value with the following line, and the curl command get the param, but i can't add IP before and /health after.

Could you help me to finalize this command line ?

```
cat ms-something-*/application.properties | grep server.port | awk '{print $3}' | xargs curl
```

So without the last element "xargs curl", the line return a list of port number. but i need to add the ip (for example 8.8.8.8) and /health, to call curl on `"8.8.8.8:server.port/health"`

Comment: Can you post the contents of `application.properties` file on which `grep` on server port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat ms-something-*/application.properties | grep server.port | awk '{print "8.8.8.8:"$3"/health"}' | xargs curl
```

should work for you, if I correctly understand your question...

Comment: If I understand right, you are missing a `:` right after the IP and just before port value.

Comment: That's it ! i was trying to echo something but i don't think about concat inside the print... It work fine. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this also with a for loop.

```
for port in $(cat ms-something-*/application.properties | grep server.port | awk '{print $3}') ; do 
    curl "8.8.8.8:${port}/health"
done
```